# how to record calls using MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK

Tags: android, call-recording

I want to record calls only (But only my voice or the person who has my app installed) but *VOICE_UPLINK* is not working , but MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC is working and recording audio of both caller and recipient

I've tried :-
sources as :- `MIC , VOICE_CALL , DEFAULT , VOICE_COMMUNICATION , CAMCORDER , UPLINK , DOWNLINK`

but **Uplink** and **Downlink** is not working

When I use Uplink or downlink my app misbehave while When I use other sources my app works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to permission

> user-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT"  >

Which is only granted to system apps , as *VOICE_UPLINK* and *VOICE_DOWNLINK* requires this permission 3rd party applications are not granted this permission

**It also depend on manufacturer , which can restrict users from recording calls. It maybe done by hardware or software.**

These are the two possible reasons I think why This ain't working